# kubectl top node output does not match Linux free command

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I have a one a one node Kubernetes cluster and the memory usage reported by the metrics server does not seem to be the same as the memory usage shown with the `free` command

```
# kubectl top nodes
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
<node_ip>   1631m        10%    13477Mi         43%

# free -m
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32010       10794         488          81       20727       19133
Swap:         16127        1735       14392
```

And the difference is significant ~ 3 GB.

I have also tested this on a 3 node cluster, and the issue is present there too:

```
# kubectl top nodes
NAME          CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
<node_ip1>   1254m        8%     26211Mi         84%
<node_ip2>   221m         1%     5021Mi          16%
<node_ip3>   363m         2%     8731Mi          28%
<node_ip4>   1860m        11%    20399Mi         66%

# free -m (this is on node 1)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          32010        5787         369        1676       25853       24128
Swap:         16127           0       16127
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: @jww Kubernetes stuff is generally kept on here to avoid splitting the community.

Comment: @coderanger - see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jww Unfortunately SO global policy has not kept pace with the realities of modern system operations where questions cross all of those lines. Thanks for the heads up but things are well taken care of :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question can be found [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/985501/kubectl-top-command-output-does-not-match-linux-free-command). It is a duplicate so you can remove this post from StackOverflow.

Comment: just leave it please

Answer (score -1):

The metrics exposed by the Metrics Server are collected by an instance of [cAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor) on each node. What you see in the output of `kubectl top node` is how cAdvisor determines the current resource usage.

So, apparently cAdvisor and `free` determine the resource usage in different ways. To find out why, you would need to dig into internals of how cAdvisor and `free` work.